# How can I upload duplicate files in remote location using java ftpclient

Tags: java, file, remote-server, ftp-client

I am trying to upload files to remote server using java FTPSClient. If I try to upload duplicate files I am getting error response with reply code as 550. Is there anyway to upload duplicate files using FTPSClient.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to copy a file in FTP server using FTPClient in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37663865/how-to-copy-a-file-in-ftp-server-using-ftpclient-in-java)

Comment: Have a look to this as well: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808799/ftp-copy-a-file-to-another-place-in-same-ftp/3808815#3808815]

Comment: Check also this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19614060/java-ftp-550-error for 550 error